# Android Bundle - Start Activity and set a bundle to Null

Tags: android, bundle

I'm trying to start an Activity, which includes Bundles. I'm trying to set this bundles to be null for now since nothing has yet been passed on to this activity.

```
public class DailyActivities  extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
     TextView scoreA
    int gotA;
    int counter_score;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          counter_score=0;
          int questions_1 = 26;

        initialize();

          ///////PSEUDO CODE...this is where Im trying to say, if no bundled is passed,
          ////////then setText for scoreA to the int counter score, 
           ////////so that the activity doesn't crash due to null pointer exception////
        Bundle gotA = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(gotA == null){ 
        scoreA.setText(counter_score);
          }else if (gotA != null){
        gotLetterA = gotA.getInt("key");
         counter_score = gotLetterA;
         int percentage = (int)( gotLetterA * 100.0 / questions_1 + 0.5);
         scoreA.setText(percentage);

   }   
}
```

Currently activity crashes with the a android.resources not found error

**edit- added error log**

> 08-24 10:39:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(21177): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-24 10:39:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(21177): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.app/com.test.app.DailyActivities}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
>   08-24 10:39:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(21177):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
>   08-24 10:39:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(21177):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
>   08-24 10:39:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(21177):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
>   08-24 10:39:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(21177):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
>   08-24 10:39:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(21177):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   08-24 10:39:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(21177):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   08-24 10:39:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(21177):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>   08-24 10:39:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(21177):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   08-24 10:39:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(21177):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   08-24 10:39:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(21177):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   08-24 10:39:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(21177):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   08-24 10:39:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(21177):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   08-24 10:39:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(21177): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
>   08-24 10:39:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(21177):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:229)
>   08-24 10:39:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(21177):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3620)
>   08-24 10:39:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(21177):    at com.MovilTeacher_titan.app.DailyActivities.onCreate(DailyActivities.java:164)
>   08-24 10:39:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(21177):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
>   08-24 10:39:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(21177):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
>   08-24 10:39:33.180: E/AndroidRuntime(21177):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)

Soooooo here is the solution, I was being dense lol

```
Bundle gotA = getIntent().getExtras();{ 
if(gotA == null){ scoreA.setText("0%"); 
}else { 
myPkg = gotA.getInt("key"); 
counter_score = myPkg; 
int percentage = (int)( myPkg * 100.0 / questions_1 + 0.5);

scoreA.setText(""+percentage); 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

percentage is an int.  Your call to setText(percentage) is expecting a resource ID, not a percentage value.

Try this:  setText(""+percentage).

This will convert percentage to a string and pass that to setText() instead.

p.s. WOUNDEDSteveJones is right too, you need a call to findViewById(), but I'm guessing you have that somewhere or this app would have crashed in a different way.

Comment: Thnx - you are right about the percentage being a int, didn't see that,yet its still crashing and yes I do have `scoreA = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counterA);` I just didn't post the entire code because Im pretty certain that the issue lies with the Bundle..If I remove the mention of a bundle the activity loads fine..

Comment: I see that your'e doing setText(counter_score), so the same issue about resource IDs pertains there as well.  Try setText(""+counter_score) instead.  Other than that, I don't see anything particularly wrong with your code.

Comment: Yeah - I saw that thnx I solved it with entering a ("0") here is the final code

`Bundle gotA = getIntent().getExtras();{
  if(gotA == null){ 
  scoreA.setText("0%");
  
        }else {
  myPkg = gotA.getInt("key");
     counter_score = ,myPkg;
     int percentage = (int)( myPkg * 100.0 / questions_1 + 0.5);
     scoreA.setText(""+percentage);
        }
        }`  

Thank again!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you never are assigning scoreA to that text field.

You need to add something like `scoreA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);` before you reference it.

Comment: thnx for the help, my bad I left that part of the code out..but yes Im referencing it..`scoreA = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counterA);`